# Mongodb date with time is not working properly

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie to `mongodb`. I am writing a query to fetch documents between two dates with time. If the dates range falls in past days then giving results correctly `(like 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z to 2017-02-01T23:59:59.999Z)`. If the date range falls within today then it is giving records wrongly `(like 2017-02-20T00:00:00.000Z to 2017-02-20T16:59:59.999Z)`. Below is the query

`db.collection.count({"date1":{$gte:ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")},"date1":{$lte:ISODate("2017-02-01T23:59:59.999Z")}});`

it gives count as **221**. Now for today:

`db.collection.count({"date1":{$gte:ISODate("2017-02-20T00:00:00.000Z")},"date1":{$lte:ISODate("2017-02-20T16:59:59.999Z")}});`

it gives me count as **56**. If I add a new record after this`(2017-02-20T16:59:59.999Z)` time then the same query giving me count as **57**. Also, I tried with `$and` operator but the same result.

Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the newly added document?

Comment: This is  `2017-02-20T16:59:59.999Z` today in UTC time. I think you are getting mixed up between local time and UTC time. What timezone are you in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code.

```
db.collection.count({"date1":{$gte:ISODate("2017-02-20T00:00:00.000Z") ,$lte:ISODate("2017-02-20T16:59:59.999Z")}});
```